# GCE: 'Failed to register layer'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-container-registry

I'm attempting to pull updated containers from GCR for a Compute Engine instance. When doing so, I use the `gcloud pull` command to cause the instance to pull the latest from Google's Container Registry. 
I can see the pull initiate on the instance - however, the container is never updated (as verified by running `docker images` on the instance and looking at the creation time).

Looking through the logs on the instance, I've seen a number of errors like this:

```
{"errorDetail":{"message":"failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): failed to mknod(\"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.a\", S_IFCHR, 0): file exists"},"error":"failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): failed to mknod(\"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.a\", S_IFCHR, 0): file exists"}
```

Anyone know what I'm looking at here?

Comment: I suspect file system corruption. Run an `fsck` command. Try to manually remove the container image from your VM instance, prune images (docker image prune) and try another pull. Check the file permission on the reported file and parent directory.

Comment: This may be related to https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/issues/1162 which describes the same error message